# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null Flask-SocketIO

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to create a flaks-socketio chat app program by following tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJC8A_7VZOA

I am trying to print " has joined the chat" or stuff like that in a div

**chat.html javascript**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    const socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:5000");

    socket.on('connect', function(){
        socket.emit('join_room',{
            username: "{{ username }}",
            room: "{{ room}}"
        })
    })

    socket.on('join_room_announcement', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.username !== "{{ username }}") {
            const newNode = document.createElement('div');
            newNode.innerHTML = `<b>${data.username}</b> has joined the room`;
            document.getElementsByName('messages').append(newNode);
        }
    });

</script>
```

I am excluding the css code cause i guess it isnt that necessary.

Here is my **app.py**

```
@app.route('/chat')
def chat():
    username = request.args.get('username')
    room = request.args.get('room')

    if username and room:
        return render_template('chat.html',username=username,room=room)
    else:
        return "Bad/incomplete Request Errror Code 405/400"

@socketio.on('join_room')
def handle_join_room_event(data):
    print("{} has joined room {}".format(data["username"],data["room"]))
    # logging.info("{} has joined room {}".format(data["username"],data["room"]))
    join_room(data['room'])
    socketio.emit('join_room_announcement', data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,debug=True)
```

I am getting error Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByName(...).append is not a function

I am attaching a screenshot for referance:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2mJ5.png)

Comment: Are there any 'messages' elements in your html document?
You can use a browser console to paste the javascript in and see if necessary.

Comment: Yes, i have got one

Comment: There is not enough code here to be sure but you can put 'document.getElementsByName('messages') into a log statement and then inspect it in the browser console to see what it is and why append is not applicable to it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i was an idiot.
I had to change

`<div id = messages`>
to
`<div id =messages>`